# Symfony deserialize null value on ManyToOne relation

Tags: symfony, json-deserialization

I can't seem to find out to deserialize a json object to a null value on a ManyToOne relation.

So as example my entities would look something like this:

```
Product
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: true)]
    #[Groups([SerializationGroupConstants::PRODUCT])]
    private ?string $name = null;


    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true, onDelete: 'set null')]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(
        targetEntity: Group::class
    )]
    #[Groups([SerializationGroupConstants::PRODUCT])]
    private ?Group $group = null;
```

```
Group
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: true)]
    #[Groups([SerializationGroupConstants::GROUP])]
    private ?string $name = null;
```

An example of the product json would be as follows:

```
{
 "id": 123,
 "name": "product 123",
 "groupId": null
}
```

The deserializer is as follows:

```
$this->serializer->deserialize(
               $data,
                Product::class,
                'json',
                [
                   AbstractNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE => $existingEntity,
                   AbstractObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT => true,
                   AbstractObjectNormalizer::SKIP_NULL_VALUES => false
             ]
            );
```

My issue is that whenever the groupId property contains an id, the relation field is updated accordingly in the database. But when the groupId property is null, the relation field is not updated to null, instead it still contains the old id.

I'm currently still on Symfony 5.3.*

Comment: there has to be some glue/controller code between the json and the database. could you show that? some controller code would do the deserialization ...

Comment: @Jakumi I've added the deserializer in the example.

Comment: alright. The skip_null_values is for serialization only, so that's not really doing anything. I have a theory that goes like this, you might have a Product::setGroup() function, which will probably be used, when the group can be fetched via id, but you might not have a (public) Product::setGroupId function. I am wondering about why the field in json is called groupId and not group, seems odd to me. Can you try with group instead of groupId and see if this works for the null value. If it does, try with a non-null value for group. I mean ... I don't see a groupId property on your Product.

Comment: if there are relevant setters and getters you could show those too, but I wonder which denormalizers are used by symfony, because the default normalizers wouldn't work with the groupId thing, but would assign null to a groupId field (which I don't see but that's besides the point).

Comment: however, in the end you could just reset the group to null if the data is null, which obviously isn't how it's supposed to be ;o/

Comment: @Jakumi I've had another go at it again today. 

It turns out there was a extra denormalizer specifically for resolving the groupId to a Group entity that I missed.This denormalizer had a early return for when the given id was null and so it would not be processed,

Comment: that sounds great. I bet the solution you found would be helpful for others, if you have the time to post an answer to you question ;o)